# C# anything but null command?

Tags: c#, null

I have this program I am making in C#, and I need it to filter out all of the strings that the user sets. What I am trying to have it do is find a command that is like:

```
if (exampleString == anythingButNull);
```

If anyone can help me with a command or something that can replace the "anythingButNull" that would be very helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `exampleString != null`?

Comment: Are you OK with an empty string, @MicahVertal?

Comment: Very basic...google before asking on stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by asking the question - what do I *really* want to exclude?

Try this if you wish to exclude nulls and empty strings

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exampleString))
```

This one excludes white space as well

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exampleString))
```

In the case you really do just want a pure `null` exclusion, it's as simple as

```
if(exampleString != null)
```

**References:**

[MSDN - String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN - String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What I want to exclude is null. So, if the exampleString is anything but null or empty, I want it to run the code below. Will the code above work for that?

Comment: @MicahVertal Yes. I've given three different options, however, depending on if you care about an empty string or white space. Pick whichever one fits your scenario. If you want to exclude only null or empty then choose the first option.

Answer (score 4):

What about 'not null' (required reading : the [`!=` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx)):

```
if (exampleString != null)
```

I would suggest though to use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exampleString))
```

Comment: Also, you can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExampleString);`